# Firebase submitting details to the database, how to delay the progress bar?

Tags: android

I am not sure if my approach is appropriate or not. I have a submission form for the user in which they fill out several fields and it is then submitted to Firebase's Real time database, I am using a progress dialog just to inform the user that something is happening. When the submission is successful, the user is brought back to the main page.

My code works perfectly fine however when I test the submission is so quick that the progress bar disappears within seconds and the user is brought back to the main page. My plan is to somehow delay the operation so the user sees the progress bar however I am not sure how to approach it  or if it is recommended to use a toast instead?

**Listener for the button**

```
// submitting our details
        submitReservation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // start the progress bar
                alertDialog.show();
                // When the user presses cancel we replace the current fragment back to the users reservation

                // get our text fields
                String fullname = fullNameText.getText().toString().trim();
                String license = licenseText.getText().toString().trim();
                String time_selection = spinner_time.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String duration = spinner_duration.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String slotSelection = spinner_slot_select.getSelectedItem().toString();

                // Call our validation
                int response = validateReservation(fullname, license, time_selection, duration, slotSelection);

                // if all fields are validated, then we can submist to Firebase
                if (response == 0)
                {
                    // we need the currently logged in user's id
                    String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    // construct our reservation object
                    Reservation reservation = new Reservation(currentUser, fullname, license, time_selection, duration, slotSelection, "Progress");

                    // call our method
                    submitDetailsFirebase(reservation);

                }}}
```

**Submission to Firebase**

```
private void submitDetailsFirebase(Reservation reservation)
    {
        // make a local reference which should only be instantiated when we need it to clean up memory
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Reservations");
        // get a new key
        String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(reservation).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
            {



                // Replace the current view with the my reservations page
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_container_main, new ReserveSpace()).commit();

                // dismiss the dialog
                alertDialog.dismiss();


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Users should not be unnecessarily viewing UI updates if possible. So a Toast would be better for quick UI change updates.

Comment: I would consider leaving your implementation as it is until you've done some real world testing. You'll often find that the ideal conditions you experience during development are not always reproducible in the real world where mobile (and less than perfect) networks are common.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, much appreciated. Sometimes find it hard to make these decisions as you always want the end user to have the best experience as possible.